# How to duplicate a sprite with physics properties then add it to the scene?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skphysicsbody

I have a sprite in my scene editor, called "redsprite" with some physics properties. I really want to use this sprite for the next.

I would like to "duplicate" this sprite, keeping his physics properties, but with a new position.

```
let sprite:SKSpriteNode = (self.childNode(withName: "redsprite") as! SKSpriteNode).copyWithPhysicsBody()
sprite.position = CGPoint(x:100,y:100)
self.addChild(sprite)
```

I use an SKSpriteNode extension to copy the sprite.

```
extension SKSpriteNode  {
    func copyWithPhysicsBody()->SKSpriteNode {
       let node = self.copy() as! SKSpriteNode
       node.physicsBody = self.physicsBody
       return node
    }
}
```

I have this classical error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Cant add body, already exists in a world', reason: 'Cant add body <SKPhysicsBody> type:<Rectangle> representedObject:[<SKSpriteNode> name:'redsprite' texture:['nil'] position:{100, 100} scale:{1.49, 1.40} size:{149.15391540527344, 140.06228637695312} anchor:{0.5, 0.5} rotation:0.00], already exists in a world'
```

I understood the error, it's very clear, but I don't find a way to avoid it.

Answer (score 3):

You are taking the original body and putting it on 2 nodes. You cant do that.

As far as I remember,  physicsBody now gets copied in the copy command (it didn't always). So you should not need to transfer the original body over.  If it doesn't copy, then do:

`node.physicsBody = self.physicsBody.copy()`

Comment: incredibly, it DOES NOT copy the settings of physicsBody, when you do a deep copy, it seems.  (late 2017)  How laughable.